# keyboard not typing in windows 7 but drivers showing updated

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

i installed an antivirus , scanned and deleted the items found as malware. suddenly my keyboard doesn't function . i check device manager and both 'hid keyboard  device' drivers are showing updated. i have done troubleshooting and nothing shows for keyboard. i even installed  keyboard .dll in system32 and syswow folders. thinking it might have a role but it doesn't . please help what to do. imagine  tying  all this  using on screen keyboard

Comment: What antivirus and what have you deleted?

Comment: Does another keyboard work?

Answer (score 1):

> I installed an antivirus , scanned and deleted the items found as
> malware.

Malware can be a real problem in Windows 7 (no more security updates).

Try running SFC from an Admin Command prompt.  SFC /SCANNOW .  Restart when done and test.

If that does not work, back up all your data and re-install Windows 7.  Consider at this time upgrading to Windows 10 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @sambhav and welcome to SuperUser.

When devices start to miswork, normally try uninstalling it on Device Manager (WIN+R -> devmgmt.msc, but leaving the checkbox blank when it offers to remove them too) and 'Scan for hardware changes' again. It will detect the device and set it like newly added.

Additional to this, solution proposed by @John.

Additional question: Can you enter the BIOS by pressing desired key? I mean this for discarding hardware issues.

Have a great day!